# Determine a Node's Name/Namespace from within the Node (C++)

Tags: ros, c++, namespace, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is there a way to determine the name of a node and/or its namespace from within the node's C++?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30908/determine-a-node%27s-name/namespace-from-within-the-node-(c++)/) by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 353 on 2012-03-30

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use [ros::this_node::getName()](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1this__node.html#a2a991f67172b59ccd7e5b4aeca9b76b7) and [ros::this_node::getNamespace()](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1this__node.html#ad14aeb962672507127f0cecda2e5f825).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 19

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2022-08-28**:
To get just the node name without the namespace:

```
ros::this_node::getName().substr(ros::this_node::getNamespace().size() + 1);
```